# How to store a Big Number?

Tags: contract-deployment, bignumber, integers

I need to determine an `expiry date` for a contract a for this I use the foloowing code as the constructor of the contract :

```
constructor(address _recipient, uint256 duration)
        public
        payable
    {
        sender = msg.sender;
        recipient = _recipient;
        expiration = now + duration; // Here we determine the expiry date.
    }
```

However when I want to determine this expiry date for `one day` `(60 * 60 * 24 = 86400 seconds)` at the time of deploying this contract using the following `web3.js` commands :

```
const thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
thisContract.deploy({  
        data: bytecode,
        arguments: [ "0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2", [86400/*here is duration*/] ]
    }).send({
       from: "0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163",
       gas: 5000000 ,
       gasPrice: '3000000000',
       value: 5000 
    },
    function(error, transactionHash) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(transactionHash);
        console.log('function exec');
    }).then(function(newContractInstance) {
    console.log('Contract Instance:' + newContractInstance.options.address);
});
```

Then, I receive the following error concerning converting the `Integer` to `Big Number` :

> ***Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number [3600] to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "3600"***

And here is the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You entered an array of one number instead of the number itself.

Change

`arguments: [ "0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2", [86400/*here is duration*/] ]`

to

`arguments: [ "0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2", 86400]`

and it should work

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

> [number-to-bn] while converting number [3600] to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "3600"

This means that instead of `[3600]` you should pass either one of the following:

- `3600`
- `"0xE10"`
- `web3.utils.toBN(3600)`
- `new BigNumber(3600)`

For the last option, be sure to install BigNumber v7.0.0 or later, for compatibility with Web3 v1.x (otherwise you might get other runtime errors at a later point).